# Is the zero exit status different to that of boolean logic when using the Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I understand that if I execute a command in the shell with the ampersand operators e.g. `command1&&command2` and should the first command execute successfully it does so with a zero exit status.

Is this similar or different to that of boolean logic whereby 0 is false and 1 is true or have I understood it incorrectly?

Does the type of shell you use make a difference? I am currently running the Bourne-Again Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell mostly is 0 to indicate zero errors and success, so yes in this sense it is true logically, unlike in many programming languages where 0  usually is false. Although modern languages tend to have distinct logical values of true and false these days.

Comment: All the shells I know. I said mostly because I do not know all the shells.

Comment: Thanks. How does this differ to a non-zero exit status for example when using control operators such as `||` in command such as `command1||command2`?

Comment: It means if command1 fails then execute command2, that is command1 exit status is nonzero.

Comment: Wonder why they chose the opposite representation of boolean values.

Comment: Here is a good explanation, http://ry.ca/blog/category/tech/unix/ but as to why only mr. Bourne who developed the original grandfather of all shells would know. I guess it just means 0 or no error, thus success, thus true.

Comment: @johnshen64 One of the sneakiest things I've ever seen `||` used for is a one line "first run" test. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4770/2873

Answer (score 1):

The better rationale is that there is really only one 'success', but there are multiple reasons for a 'failure': file not found, argument error, computational error, etc.  This was a convention of the OS, not just of the shell, in the interprocess communications - the return code sent by the `exit(2)` system call and received by the `wait(2)` call.